# How to treat absolute value in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have worked through a separable first-order ODE to get the following:

$$
|y|=e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}}
$$

There is an initial value of y(2) = -3

It is easy to then plug this in and find a value for C1.

However, when then presenting the final solution, would I create a new C2 such that:

$$
C_{2}=\pm C_{1}
$$

Or leave it in as is, and sub in C the value of C1

Or do the following?

$$
y=\pm e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}}
$$

Comment: The second one where $\pm e^{c_1}$ can be any real number.

Comment: Is function $y$ continuous?

Comment: Yep it's continuous

Comment: @crumpybum please reply to our answers in order for us to know if we provided any help or if we confused you more!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you tried to do is the following:

$$
|y| = e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}} \Rightarrow
(y=e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}} \forall x\in \mathbb{R}))\space or \space
(y=-e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}))
$$

The problem here is that if $y$ is not continuous, then the above does not hold, but the following is true:

$$
|y| = e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}} \Rightarrow
(\exists A_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}: y=e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}}\space\forall x\in A_1)\space and \space
(\exists A_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}: y=-e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}}\space\forall x\in A_2)
$$

However, if we know that $y$ is continous we can manipulate the equation as follows. We first of all know that $e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}} \neq 0 \Rightarrow |y| \neq 0 \Rightarrow y\neq 0$

From Bolzano's theorem it follows that since $y$ is continuous and not equal to $0$ it has positive or negative sign across the whole domain, but not both. We know that $y(2) = -3$  so we can conclude that $y < 0 \space \forall x\in R$. Hence:
$$y=-e^{\frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} e^{c_{1}}\space\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

From here you can finish the exercise! I hope I helped!

Comment: Sorry about not responding sooner, I've been super busy. Your answer makes perfect sense, but I don't think I'll be able to use this justification in my solution as it's a bit outside the scope of my course. Thank you very much though, it's very useful information to know!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would solve
$$
\ln|y(x)|=\frac12\arctan(\frac x2)+c_1
$$
as
$$
y(x)=C_1e^{\frac12\arctan(\frac x2)}
$$
where $C_1=\pm e^{c_1}$ also adjusts for the sign of $y(x)$. This form then also contains the case of the zero function as solution with $C_1=0$.

Then compute
$$
C_1=y_0e^{-\frac12\arctan(\frac{x_0}2)}=-3e^{-\frac\pi8}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes perfect sense: I'll make sure to use this in my solution :)